# Do I need to run AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID in Thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I'm using AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID to play sound, it works fine except I'm not sure if I need to run it on a thread block or, by itself it run on it's own thread.

I'm just afraid it might make my application not responsive if it's run on main thread.

```
NSURL *tapSound   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"mysound"
                                                withExtension: @"aiff"];

    // Store the URL as a CFURLRef instance
    //   soundFileURLRef = (__bridge CFURLRef) tapSound ;

    // Create a system sound object representing the sound file.

     SystemSoundID  soundFileObject;

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (

                                      (__bridge_retained CFURLRef) tapSound,
                                      &soundFileObject
                                      );
    // AudioServicesPlayAlertSound (soundFileObject);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundFileObject);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sound will play asynchronously.  You do **not** need to run it in its own thread.